# What this code do?

Tags: c++, mathematics

I investigate source code old game for 90s, dont understand math stuff.

```
#define W2V_SHIFT 14

#define PREDICTIVE_SCALE_FACTOR 14

{
z = (enemy->pos.z_pos + (enemy->speed * PREDICTIVE_SCALE_FACTOR * phd_cos(enemy->pos.y_rot) >> W2V_SHIFT)) - (item->pos.z_pos + (object->pivot_length * phd_cos(item->pos.y_rot) >> W2V_SHIFT));
x = (enemy->pos.x_pos + (enemy->speed * PREDICTIVE_SCALE_FACTOR * phd_sin(enemy->pos.y_rot) >> W2V_SHIFT)) - (item->pos.x_pos + (object->pivot_length * phd_sin(item->pos.y_rot) >> W2V_SHIFT));
    }
angle = phd_atan(z, x);
```

"enemy" is an object on the scene, for example main game character. "item" is for example tiger. Tiger attacks the main character. This source code uses fixed point math (shift with W2V_SHIFT). y_rot - rotation angle. x_pos and z_pos - position on scene. phd_sin and phd_cos - assembler fixed point math routines.

My question is - what are the results x and z in this math calculations (suppose)? And what is the angle variable? Is this the next coordinate to move the character, or what? For what in this calculation is cos() and sin()? Maybe x and z are the distance between the tiger and main character?

Definition of phd_atan() is:

```
;******************************************************************************
;*          Int phd_atan( int x,int y );
;*
;*      Entry EAX: Distance along X axis..
;*            EDX: Distance along Y axis..
;*      Exit  EAX: Angle ( 0 - 65536 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is using a common formula for [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system), expressing one point as an offset from a pivot point by some radius at a particular angle:

```
x = pivot.x + radius * cos(angle)
z = pivot.z + radius * sin(angle)
```

The left half of the x & z code is a prediction for where the enemy will be one time step in the future, given its current position, speed, and heading angle.

The second half is the position of the swiveling arm of the item, given the position of its pivot, the length of its arm, and its rotation angle.

By subtracting these halves, we get a vector pointing from the end of the item's swiveling arm to where the enemy is predicted to be.

The `atan` function is giving the heading angle of this vector.

This might be used to make the "tiger" item face toward where the enemy character is moving, anticipating its movement.

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be a parametric equation of a circle? x = r * cos(t) ; y = r * sin(t)

Comment: If you vary only t while holding r constant, it traces a circle. If you vary r while holding t constant, it traces a radial line. If you vary r proportionate to t, it traces a spiral. You can get all sorts of shapes just by changing how you vary the parameters, because it's a coordinate space that covers the whole plane.